# PHP code for generating decent-looking coupon codes (mix of letters and numbers)

Tags: php, random

For an ecommerce site I want to generate a random coupon code that looks better than a randomly generated value. It should be a readable coupon code, all in uppercase with no special characters, only letters (A-Z) and numbers (0-9).

Since people might be reading this out / printing it elsewhere, we need to make this a simple-to-communicate value as well, perhaps 8-10 characters long.

Something like perhaps,

```
AHS3DJ6BW 
B83JS1HSK
```

(I typed that, so it's not really that random)

Comment: *(related)* http://seancoates.com/blogs/arbitrary-incrementer-in-php

Comment: As an sidepoint to the question, make sure that you retain a record of used keys so that you do not create duplicates!

Comment: Wow - thanks guys! Can we have some estimates (or real data!) on how fast each of these functions are? I tried one on a Windows machine and it took like a second to pop out 5!

Comment: As you will probably need to keep track of the results, so as not to create duplicates (as suggested by Stephen), you could pre-compute a whole bunch of codes and store them in a database. You can then grab the next in line, and mark it as used. That may also help overcome any speed issues.

Comment: If this is for people to read and communicate you probably want to exclude `I`, `1`, `O` and `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Johannes Rössel  - that was a good point!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
```

You can optimize this by preallocating the `$res` string and caching the result of `strlen($chars)-1`. This is left as an exercise to the reader, since probably you won't be generating thousands of coupons per second.

Comment: Now make sure that it never adds more than 4 digits :)

Comment: @Power Not a requirement in the question :p

Comment: This gives a performance of 0.4421501159668 seconds for 10000

Comment: @QAQ I got 0.652 for the unoptimized version and 0.475 for the optimized version for 100 000 (not 10 000). Your computer doesn't seem to be very fast.

Comment: @Arty - I know, but I was implying that this was the fastest of 'em all! :)

Comment: Using a slightly modified version of this - with O 0, I 1 removed.

Comment: @QAQuest - "with O 0, I 1 removed." wut?

Comment: won't this have a probability of collision of referral codes?

Comment: Proposed solution gives 36^10 = 3656158440062976 unique codes. Chance to have same code even if you generate billions codes is pretty small ;)

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 10)
```

Comment: @QAQuest: No, this code will return a string of ten random alphanumeric characters. If you want it in uppercase, use `strtoupper`.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't keep it simple?

```
<?php
    echo strtoupper(uniqid());
?>
```

Always returns 13 character long uppercased random code.

Comment: This is good... 0.18964600563049 seconds for 10000 . However it doesnt seem to be too random...first 6-8 characters are the same on my machine..

Comment: You can extend uniqid() function by adding a prefix parameter: strtoupper(uniqid(substr(sha1(time()), 0, 2)));

Answer (score 4):

You can use the coupon code generator PHP class file to generate N number of coupons and its customizable, with various options of adding own mask with own prefix and suffix. [Simple PHP coupon code generator](https://github.com/joashp/simple-php-coupon-code-generator)

Example:
 `coupon::generate(8); // J5BST6NQ`

Answer (score 1):

http://webarto.com/35/php-random-string-generator

Here you go.

```
function randr($j = 8){
$string = "";
    for($i=0;$i < $j;$i++){
        srand((double)microtime()*1234567);
        $x = mt_rand(0,2);
        switch($x){
            case 0:$string.= chr(mt_rand(97,122));break;
            case 1:$string.= chr(mt_rand(65,90));break;
            case 2:$string.= chr(mt_rand(48,57));break;
        }
    }
return strtoupper($string); //to uppercase
}
```

Comment: Changed it a bit:         switch($x){
            case 0:$string.= chr(mt_rand(65,90));break;
            case 1:$string.= chr(mt_rand(48,57));break;
        }
Time taken for 10000, 1.667200088501 seconds

Comment: $x = mt_rand(0,2); > $x = mt_rand(0,1);

Because case 2 doesn't exist, I added strtoupper to avoid modifying upper code, in case he wanted to use lowercase :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no security requirements for these, then you don't really need randomly generated codes. I would just use incremental IDs, such as those generated by whatever RDBMS you use. Optionally, if you have different types of coupons, you could prefix the codes with something, e.g.:

```
CX00019 QZ0001C
CX0001A QZ0001D
CX0001B QZ0001E
```

Alternately, you could even use dictionary words in the coupon, as such coupon codes are easier to remember and faster for users to type. Companies like Dreamhost use these for their promo codes, e.g.:

```
Promo60
NoSetupFee
YELLOWGORILLA82
```

Some of these are obviously human-created (which you might want to have the option of), but they can also be generated using a dictionary list. But even if they are randomly-generated nonsense phrases, the fact that the characters follow a logical pattern still makes it much more user-friendly than something like `R7QZ8A92F1`. So I would strongly advise against using the latter type of coupon codes just on the basis that they "look cool". Your customers will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$size = 12;

$string = strtoupper(substr(md5(time().rand(10000,99999)), 0, $size));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateCouponCode($length = 8) {
  $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $ret = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $random = str_shuffle($chars);
    $ret .= $random[0];
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: You shuffle an entire string just to get the first element?

Answer (score 0):

you can find a lot of function in php rand manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

i like this one

```
   <?php
//To Pull 8 Unique Random Values Out Of AlphaNumeric

//removed number 0, capital o, number 1 and small L
//Total: keys = 32, elements = 33
$characters = array(
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M",
"N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

//make an "empty container" or array for our keys
$keys = array();

//first count of $keys is empty so "1", remaining count is 1-7 = total 8 times
while(count($keys) < 8) {
    //"0" because we use this to FIND ARRAY KEYS which has a 0 value
    //"-1" because were only concerned of number of keys which is 32 not 33
    //count($characters) = 33
    $x = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
    if(!in_array($x, $keys)) {
       $keys[] = $x;
    }
}

foreach($keys as $key){
   $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
}
echo $random_chars;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = 9;
$code   = (strtoupper(substr(md5(time()), 0, $length)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Write

```
 $voucher_no =  date('ymd') . rand(1000, 9999);
 while(SapItem::where('voucher_no', $voucher_no)->exists()){
  $voucher_no = date('ymd') . rand(1000, 9999);
 }
```

Output: 2204171447