# How to generate a random range to get fields from mysql database, given number of records, and range limit

Tags: php, mysql, function

Haven't programmed in a while and here I am with this simple problem, basically I need to generate two random numbers that are within a maximum limit, but with set distance apart from each other in order to randomly (each time) call fields from the database using the mysql LIMIT.

ex. say there are 95 database fields ($max), fields returned = 20 ($fields) (number of fields that should be returned) or range limit 20 (ie difference between min - max is 20)

```
SELECT...............  LIMIT $a, $fields
$a - $b = 20
$b < 95
```

I just use ...

```
 $a = floor(mt_rand(0, ($max-$fields)));
```

to generate an $a and use the $fields value which gives me all the info I need (ie from where to start getting the records ($a) and how many records to get ($fields))

Any ideas on another way on how to do this?

Comment: Try reading before writing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521621/php-code-for-generating-decent-looking-coupon-codes-mix-of-alphabets-and-number follow this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If your table is always bigger then the required distance of the two random numbers you can go about it like this:

```
// $row_count is the number of rows you have in the database 
$max = mt_rand($distance, $row_count);
$min = $max - $distance;
// now you can use these in sql like
$sql = "select ... offset {$min} limit {$distance}";
```

References: [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: in your case the $min (offset) is static, which is wrong in case of this question as the offset should be random, but even with $distance added to it should still be within the $row_count..

Comment: Maybe it's my engrish, but I'm afraid that i don't get your requirements. The `$min`, `$max` values generated randomly, their distance is static. If you want you can make that random too with `$distance = mt_rand(0, $row_count);`, but you question said: `...but with set distance apart from each other...`.

Comment: take a look at the example I gave (it works) in your case it would look like  $sql = "select .... offset {$a} limit {$distance}";

Comment: I'm confused. First of all, the `$min` variable is random in my example, [see it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mHcV0i).
Second of all, your one line example is hardly runnable with all the variables undefined in code, and i'm having a hard time decipher your description of them (my bad).