# Generate multiple coupon codes at once; separated by comma

Tags: php, random

I found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521621/php-code-for-generating-decent-looking-coupon-codes-mix-of-alphabets-and-number) explaining how you can generate random coupon codes.

I'm looking into using that code and generate multiple coupons at once (e.g. 50), while separate them by a comma.

The output would be: COUPON-HMECN, COUPON-UYSNC, etc.

Code below and [codepad example available](http://codepad.org/rcrucYyi).

```
      $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      $res = "COUPON-";

      for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
          $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];     
      }

      echo $res . ",";
```

Comment: @Vulcan: To generate multiple codes at once, not once every run of the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$numCodesToGenerate = 5;

for ($n = 0; $n < $numCodesToGenerate; $n++)
{
    $res = "COUPON-";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
      $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];     
    }

    echo $res . ","; 
}
```

Comment: Produces output with an additional ',' on the end.

Comment: @Max - If you use this, at-least move the `strlen($chars)-1` out of the loop as PHP will count the length of the string on every loop, or better yet, hard-code it to 36, or use the method I posted which uses the ASCII values instead of performing a string lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much neater version (and faster) that does what you need:

```
function MakeCouponCode() {
  $res = "COUPON-";
  for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
    $res .= chr(mt_rand(0, 1) == 0 ? mt_rand(65, 90) : mt_rand(48, 57));
  return $res;
}

$coupons = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
  $coupons[] = MakeCouponCode();

echo implode(', ', $coupons);
```

Output:

```
COUPON-D707Y, COUPON-4B37E, COUPON-3O397, COUPON-M799X, COUPON-24Q36
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)?

```
$coupon_str = '';
$seperator = '';

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $coupon_str .= $seperator . uniqid('COUPON-');

    $seperator = ',';
}

echo $coupon_str;
```

Output:

```
COUPON-502373ac95dd2,COUPON-502373ac95de8,COUPON-502373ac95ded,....
```

Comment: What a horrid long coupon code to have to enter by hand, also you will have an extra ',' on the end.

Comment: Its not that long in my opion. And there will be no ',' at the end of the string, look again at the code ;).

Comment: Ah, yes, your right, your pre-pending it :). that's neater then an implode as you only loop the array once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the coupon code generator PHP class file to generate N number of coupons and its customizable, with various options of adding own mask with own prefix and suffix. The coupon codes are separated by comma. [Simple PHP coupon code generator](https://github.com/joashp/simple-php-coupon-code-generator)

Example:
 `coupon::generate(8); // J5BST6NQ`