# Wordpress unique coupon code generation & print - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, random, coupon

I have been trying to implement unique code generation functionality to my theme. I am trying to explain the current function and the function that I want to get down below. 
As of theme design, a coupon code is predefined on admin panel when creating a coupon. So it is just a code that appears all the time when you click on 'display Code' button. What I want to get is a unique coupon code whenever a visitor clicks on the button. 
The way I want to do this is generating 4 decimal random string consisting of letters and numbers and paste it near to the coupon code value that I define when I create the deal.
Example: Let's say I am creating a deal for Walmart. I define the coupon code as WMT. What I want is to show coupon codes like WMT12Y4, WMTt5ff,.... whenever a visitor clicks on the button.

To do so, I found the code right below from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521621/php-code-for-generating-decent-looking-coupon-codes-mix-of-letters-and-numbers).

```
$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
```

I guess this will help me to generate 4 digits random value.

Then I need to paste it to the coupon code value, but I don't know how to by changing the code in the theme file right below. I try to add the random code generator there and $res in code but it won't work:

```
else {
        $enable_redirect = get_field('redirect_to_offer') ? 
get_field('redirect_to_offer') : array('');

        $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}

        echo'<a href="' . esc_url(get_field('url')) . '" target="_blank" 
class="btn btn-color btn-deal show-coupon-code" data-target="#discount-modal" 
data-clipboard-text="' . esc_attr(get_field('coupon_code')) . $res . '" data-
redirect="' . $enable_redirect[0] . '">' . fw_ssd_get_option('show-code-text') 
. '</a>';
    }
```

Comment: From the generated HTML it would appear that JS in browser is responsible for updating the clipboard. Are you getting any errors? Also, what's even the point of the random coupon suffix? It appears that it is generated on the spot and never stored.

Comment: I am currently not getting error with this code. I will also try to store the random code after being able to show it on clipboard. If you know a way to do them both at once, that'd be great.